# ProGuardGUI Need help to obfuscate my code

Tags: proguard, bukkit

I want to obfuscate my plugin using proguard.
But if I press "Process!" this error appear:

```
ProGuard, version 5.3.3
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\BlockParty.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\lib\rt.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\spigot-1.8.8.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\worldedit-bukkit-6.1.jar]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.meta.When]
Warning: class [nmsblocks/CBXNmsBlock_1710.class] unexpectedly contains class [CBXNmsBlock_1710]
Note: there were 1 duplicate class definitions.
  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: there were 1 classes in incorrectly named files.
     You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
     The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
     If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
     you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Where can I add the "-ignorewarnings" option? I'm using the ProGuard GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#ignorewarnings)

Also you should read about the [error](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unexpectedclass) and why it can appear.

You can add `-ignorewarnings` into your proguard.cfg or another solution could be adding this:

```
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
```

Comment: Please avoid posting only links for the important part of your answer!

Comment: ignorewarnings is not the way to go. You may hide important problems.